# Locators lookup is showing ReferenceError: "home" is not defined** in <eval>

Tags: karate

Below is my locators.json file under objects folder

```
{
  "home": {
    "signInButton": "//div[@id='root']/main/button/span",
    "selectLanguage": "//div[@id='root']/main/div/a/span"
  }
}
```

I tried below code in the feature file. But I am getting error 'javascript evaluation failed: waitFor(home.signInButton).click(), **ReferenceError: "home" is not defined** in  '

```
  Background:
    configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', showDriverLog: true }
    call read('classpath:objects/locators.json')

  Scenario: Login my app
  Given driver 'http://example.com/'
  And waitFor(home.signInButton).click()
```

I tried below code also still having issue.

```
  Background:
    configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', showDriverLog: true }
    def myObj = call read('classpath:objects/locators.json')

  Scenario: Login my app
  Given driver 'http://example.com/'
  And waitFor(myObj.home.signInButton).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs VERY carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-vs-read (see second-last row)

It should be:

```
* call read 'classpath:objects/locators.json'
```